# top and sidebar menus not showing up after upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade

I'm fairly new to ubuntu and for awhile a was using 14.04 LTS then I didn't use my computer for quite long time, so when I tried to do the regular updates, started saying that some files where missing, so, finally found a way to add those missing files one at the time, then I was able to upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

After the upgrade was competed both top and sidebar menus where gone. I tried to use [Alt][Cntl][T] but nothing happened, so finally I open a folder located on my desktop and from there I browsed the computer files until I found the Terminal, so I opened it and tried the command: unity and the top menu appeared for a second and disappeared once again.

So far I have tried several suggestions I found in this forum with no luck.

I've also tried to reinstall either 16.04 or 14.04 with either the USB drive or the DVD and nothing happens, the screen stays dark with the cursor blinking.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Try to install `CompizConfig Setings Manager` and tweak ubuntu a bit. Or reinstall ubuntu-desktop. But first, try to create another user first and see whether this user have normal look. Couple mounts ago, I had same issues, and new user resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the login screen still fine? Because if you can access the terminal I think it would be worth a try to just install a different GUI of your choice until you can restore Unity.  If you still want a somewhat Ubuntu feel I might try Gnome since it's sort of similar and easy to learn. If you decide on Gnome this guide should help you http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts